Class creation only if connection works
I have an app with multiple small modules, its with fastapi (python) and vue as the frontend.
I added a new module which uses SQLAlchemy, and then declare classes for tables using table reflection (metadata.reflect and __table__=metadata.tables[‘mytable’]
)
Because its a small module in the app, I dont want it to fail the entire program, so I have some db init function which try to connect to db and manage failures (with retry option in the ui) so all other modules will still work.
The issue that I have is with the class definition, because if the connection fails the class definition fails.
I tries to use .get(‘mytable’) but it also fails if its null.
Ive tried to define some fake table and use .get(‘mytable’) or Table(‘faketable’…)
But the issue is that if connection fails at first, the colums of the fake tables take effect and after connecting successfully, the columns dont update to the columns of ‘mytable’.
I thought about 2 options:

Define the classes in a function and call that function on successful init.
“Update” or “refresh” the classes after successful init (but I dont know how to do it.


You can define the classes within a function and call this function only after a successful connection to the database. This way :
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

def init_db(engine):
    metadata = MetaData()
    metadata.reflect(bind=engine)

    class Table(Base):
        __table__ = metadata.tables.get('table')

    return Table

def try_init_db(connection_string):
    try:
        engine = create_engine(connection_string)
        Table = init_db(engine)
        return Table
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to connect to database: {e}")
        return None

# Example usage:
connection_string = "connection_string"
Table = try_init_db(connection_string)
if Table:
    # Proceed with using Table
    pass
else:
    # Handle the error
    pass


But what is I use this class in other functions?
If its not declared it will fail… should I also create the API routes on condition? Or because you return the class and not an instance, I can declare it in global and reassign it when init is successful
